# How to make functions for reverse number guessing game?

Tags: c++, function, random

For my assignment, I need to make a program that guesses the user's number, between 1-19 inclusively, within 5 tries. For each try, the user inputs if the number is: a) correct, b) too high, or c) too low

We are supposed to define two functions:

- The first is a function that takes a number (`int`) as a parameter and outputs the prompt to the user that guesses that number (tells the user `"Is this your number: <guess>"`) and shows them a menu that explains how to enter correct, high, or low.
- The second function is supposed to calculate the next guess after being told if it is too high or too low.

I was able to accomplish this with nested `switch` statements, but I am having trouble trying to come up with the second function.

Any help is appreciated. I will try to attach my first program with the `switch` statements. I assume I need to generate a random number with the min and max, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int guess = 10;
    int input = 0;
    cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
    cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
    cin>> input;
    switch(input) {
        case(1):
            cout<< "Thanks for playing";
            break;
        case(2):
            guess = 5;
            cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
            cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
            cin>> input;
                switch(input){
                    case(1):
                        cout<< "Thanks for playing";
                        break;
                    case(2):
                        guess = 3;
                        cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
                        cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
                        cin>> input;
                        switch (input){
                            case(1):
                                cout<< "Thanks for playing";
                                break;
                            case(2):
                                guess = 2;
                                cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
                                                       cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
                                                       cin>> input;
                                switch(input){
                                    case(1):
                                        cout<< "Thanks for playing";
                                        break;
                                    case (2):
                                        guess = 1;
                                        cout<< "Your guess was: "<<guess<<endl;
                                        break;
                                    case (3):
                                        cout<< "Cheater..."<<endl;
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;
                            case(3):
                                guess = 4;
                                cout<< "Your guess was: "<<guess<<endl;
                                break;

                              }
                        break;
                    case(3):
                        guess = 7;
                        cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
                        cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
                        cin>> input;
                        switch (input){
                            case (1):
                                cout<< "Thanks for playing";
                                break;
                            case(2):
                                guess = 6;
                                cout<< "Your guess was: "<<guess<<endl;
                                break;
                            case(3):
                                guess = 8;
                                cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
                                cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
                                cin>> input;
                                switch (input){
                                        case (1):
                                        cout<< "Thanks for playing";
                                        break;
                                        case(2):
                                        cout<<"Cheater..."<<endl;
                                        case(3):
                                        guess = 9;
                                        cout<< "Your guess was: "<< guess<<endl;
                                        break;
                                }
                        }

                        break;
                }
            break;
        case(3):
            guess = 15;
            cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
            cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
            cin>> input;
                switch(input){
                    case(1):
                        cout<< "Thanks for playing";
                        break;
                    case(2):
                        guess = 13;
                        cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
                        cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
                        cin>> input;
                        switch (input){
                            case(1):
                                cout<< "Thanks for playing";
                                break;
                            case(2):
                                guess = 12;
                                cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
                                                       cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
                                                       cin>> input;
                                switch(input){
                                    case(1):
                                        cout<< "Thanks for playing";
                                        break;
                                    case (2):
                                        guess = 11;
                                        cout<< "Your guess was: "<<guess<<endl;
                                        break;
                                    case (3):
                                        cout<< "Cheater..."<<endl;
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;
                            case(3):
                                guess = 14;
                                cout<< "Your guess was: "<<guess<<endl;
                                break;
                              }
                        break;
                    case(3):
                        guess = 17;
                        cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
                        cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
                        cin>> input;
                        switch (input){
                            case (1):
                                cout<< "Thanks for playing";
                                break;
                            case(2):
                                guess = 16;
                                cout<< "Your guess was: "<<guess<<endl;
                                break;
                            case(3):
                                guess = 18;
                                cout<<"Is this your number: "<< guess<<endl;
                                cout<< "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)"<<endl;
                                cin>> input;
                                switch (input){
                                        case (1):
                                        cout<< "Thanks for playing";
                                        break;
                                        case(2):
                                        cout<<"Cheater..."<<endl;
                                        case(3):
                                        guess = 19;
                                        cout<< "Your guess was: "<< guess<<endl;
                                        break;
                                }
                        }

                        break;
                }
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This pattern of nested inputs and switch statements is bad design, and should be restarted from scratch. Focus on writing the functions first, but only have your program call each function once (that's one guess, and one input from the user). AFTER you have that working, you encase that in a loop.

Comment: Let's play a game. You have to guess a number between 1 and 19 inclusive. I will tell you if it's correct, too high, or too low. Which number do you guess first and why?

Comment: Why do you think the guesses would be random?  Is that how you would do it if you were playing this yourself?

Comment: As John has indicated - the design is not optimal.  It doesn't scale.  Suppose tomorrow the assignment is for numbers between 0 and 1000 - what would you do?  Is there a pattern?  How can you avoid writing the pattern over and over?

Comment: Follow the requirements of the assignment. Write two functions that do exactly what the assignment requires them to do, no more, no less. Then think about how to combine them to create the final algorithm. You're trying to attack the problem by hard coding every possible specific case using a bunch of switch statements without taking a step back and thinking about how you can write a general algorithm that works for all cases.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.I am trying to figure out how to code the second algorithm. I'm just not sure how to do it with only five guesses. Can someone give me a hint without answering the question for me? Am I supposed to use a conditional or try using a random number while setting the min and max based on the user inputs. I know this is a simple problem but I've only been learning for a couple of weeks. Again, thank you all for your help.

Comment: @ZachSal you just guess in the middle of the available range. The user tells you whether that's too high or too low, so each iteration you're guaranteed to cut your search space in half. If I guess 10, you say "too low", then I know that 1-10 are not valid. On the second iteration, it's equivalent to starting a new game with one fewer guess and a smaller search space. "Guess a number between 11 and 19, in 4 guesses." I pick 15. You say "too high". Now it's like starting a new game with the rules "Guess a number between 11 and 14, in 3 guesses." Each iteration you adjust your guess space.

Comment: The algorithm you need is binary search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define elif else if

void guessf(int guess) {
    cout << "Is this your number: " << guess << endl << "Correct? (1), High?(2), Low(3)" << endl;
}

int main(){
    unsigned int range = 10, guess = 10, input = 0, i = 0;
    while (i < 5 && input != 1) {
        guessf(guess);
        cin >> input;
        if (range > 1)
            range /= 2;
        else
            range = 1;
        if (input == 1)
            cout << "Thanks for playing";
        elif (input == 2)
            guess -= range;
        else
            guess += range;
    }
}
```

**What this does**: the `guessf()` is pretty simple so we move on to the `main()`,the `range` variable is what it will be added or subtracted from the `guess` on each try, then, until your program does 5 tries or the `guess` is correct, ask user if it is correct, high or low, if it is correct `cout << "Thanks for playing";`, if the `guess` is high subtract the `range` and if the `guess` is low add the `range`to the `guess`. Also bcs we deal with `int`, the minimum value of `range` must be `1`, bcs if it is lower nothing will ever be added or subtracted from the `guess`. This technique is at least something similar to  **"Binary Search"**

If you want to remove `elif`, remove `#define elif else if` and replace `elif` with `else if`( `else` and `if` in the same line)

Also by 2 functions, you mean 2 including the main or without? This is an important thing to know

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations:

- The problem set consists of numbers from 1 up to 19 i.e. range [1, 19].
- The given number needs to be searched/guessed in this range.
- The range is fixed i.e. it will always be [1, 19]. That means it's a sorted range.
- The number of tries to guess the number is 5.

So, given the above characteristics, the [Binary Search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) would provide an optimal solution i.e.:

- Range = [1, 19]
- No. of tries = 5
- Worst-case performance of Binary search algorithm = `O(log n)`
- i.e. Range = 19, O(log n) = O(log 19) = 4.25 = ~5 tries

You can do some research on the Binary Search algorithm to get familiar with it. The rest would be your logic of maintaining `high`, `low` and `mid` points. And, you don't need random numbers for this!

You would be using your own variation of the Binary search algorithm that guesses the number by adjusting the problem set i.e. range where the number may exist.

---

As far as your two functions are concerned:

1. The first function would show the menu and input the number to be guessed.
2. The second function would perform the guessing.

For the rest of the boilerplate logic, you can implement that in your `main()` function.

Here's a general breakdown of your code (just a synopsis, assuming you're using C++98 or C++03):

```
int showMenuAndInputNumber() { /* ... */ }
int guessNumber(const int n) { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    const int n = showMenuAndInput();

    // validate if n is in the range [1, 19]

    // given the search sorted range and the valid number,
    // then using Binary search you'll need max 5 tries
    // so, you don't need to keep track of the tries
    // but, for simplicity, you can use tries

    const int tries = 5;
    for ( int t = 0; t < tries; ++t )
    {
        // guess the number here
        // adjust the range either right or left
        // according to your own Binary search algorithm's variation
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is not meant to be a ready-made solution to your problem. This is just to provide some guidelines.

Hope this helps!